How to partition into batch of records with max batch size limit
I want to batch the students into maximum batch size of 100, partitioned by School.
Each teacher can have 12 students.
Students of any teacher should not be split into different batches.
No. of students in a batch can be less than 100 but not more.
Fiddle URL
With the query used in the fiddle, for the second batch the number students are more than 100 (RowNum 17-32).
How can I ensure the students are not split into different batches and there are no more than 100 students in a batch.
3rd party edit
This sample shows rows with RowNum > 14. Some have a CumulativeCount over 100 and a Batchnumber of 2.

The inner query is nearly the same only order by was moved to the CTE.
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT School, TeacherName,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SCHOOL ORDER BY sCHOOL) 
         AS RowNum,
         SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY School ORDER BY TeacherName) 
         AS CumulativeCount,
         SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY School 
                       ORDER BY TeacherName)/100+1 
         AS BatchNumber
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY School, TeacherName )
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE  RowNum > 14
ORDER BY School


I think you need ROW_NUMBER(). The following statement is a possible option: SELECT Name, TeacherName, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY TeacherName) - 1) / @BatchSize + 1 AS BatchNumber FROM #school ORDER BY Name, TeacherName.

@Zhorov This does not work in this case as this is partitioning the records based on (number of records per School) / (batchSize)

I don't get why you expect 3 batches when you have 12 kids in a school. Is it because each teacher should get own batch?

@siggemannen This is just a mock up scenario of the problem that I am facing in a larger setup. Also no I am not trying to get every teacher their own batch.

That doesn't really answer the question, why do you expect batch #3 and why doesn't row_number work. Also, what happens if a teacher has 16 kids, which batch should it get. I think better explanation / better test data is needed here

What happen if you have more than 7 students under a School & Teacher ? Please include in your sample data and expected result

It's very difficult to understand what you are actually after. Can you add the number of students in each batch to your expected output?

Updated the question with the actual considerations

so if teacher a has 33 pupils and teacher b has 33 pupils and teacher c has 33 pupilsthen thats a batch but if   teacher a has 33 pupils and teacher b has 33 pupils and teacher c has 35 pupils then batch 1 is 66 pupils (for a and b) and batch 2 has 35 pupils (for c) ? Things get complicated fast for example if a = 33 b=35 and c=33

Thanks for the update and the fiddle. Looks like a simplified variation of a knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

With the fiddle (and a better explanation) available, it becomes clear that what you have is a (somewhat) simplified version of the Knapsack Problem.
As such, it cannot be solved without recursion, unfortunately. This means that, on larger datasets, you might run into resource exhaustion issues.
The following query builds upon your fiddle:
declare @BatchSize int = 100;

with src as (
    -- Source query
    select t.School, t.TeacherName,
        count(*) as [GroupSize],
        dense_rank() over(partition by t.School order by t.TeacherName) as [RN]
    from #mytable t
    group by t.School, t.TeacherName
),
cte as (
    -- Anchor part - start of the first batch for each school
    select s.School, s.TeacherName, s.GroupSize, s.RN,
        s.GroupSize as [BatchTotal], 1 as [IsBatchStart]
    from src s
    where s.RN = 1
    union all
    -- Recursive part - deciding if current batch can be continued or not
    select s.School, s.TeacherName, s.GroupSize, s.RN,
        case
            when c.BatchTotal + s.GroupSize > @BatchSize then s.GroupSize
            else c.BatchTotal + s.GroupSize
        end as [BatchTotal],
        case
            when c.BatchTotal + s.GroupSize > @BatchSize then 1
            else 0
        end as [IsBatchStart]
    from src s
        inner join cte c on c.School = s.School
            and s.RN = c.RN + 1
)
select c.*,
    sum(c.IsBatchStart) over(partition by c.School order by c.RN) as [BatchNumber]
from cte c
order by c.School, c.RN
-- Infinite iteration - might be needed on large datasets
-- option (maxrecursion 0)

Also note that dense_rank() is a rather expensive function, performance-wise. On a larger scale I'd suggest to cache the src subquery into a temporary table with suitable indices, and then use something more lightweight, like row_number(), to number the rows.

I have updated the question with a fiddle link which has the dataset and the query used.

@SujaySalins, replaced the answer.

Thanks for that it works as expected!
